# Regex To Match &amp;entity; or &amp;#0-9; And Capture &amp;

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a replace on the following string prototype: `"I&amp;lsquo;m singing &amp; dancing in the rain."` The following regular expression matches the instance properly, but also captures the character following the instance of `&amp`. `"(&amp;)[#?a-zA-Z0-9;]"` captures the following string from the above prototype: `"&amp;l"`.

How can I limit it to only capture the `&amp;`?

**Edit:** I should add that I don't want to match `"&amp;"` by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look for (this copes with named, decimal and hexadecimal entities):

```
&amp;([A-Za-z]+|#x[\dA-Fa-f]+|#\d+);
```

replace with

```
&$1;
```

Be warned: This has a real probability to go wrong. I recommend using a HTML parser to decode the text. You can decode it twice, if it was double encoded. HTML and regex don't play well together even on the small scale.

Since you are in JavaScript, I expect you are in a browser. If you are, you have a nice DOM parser at your hands. Create a new element, assign the string to its inner HTML property and read out the text value. Done.

Comment: This works partially, but isn't matching strings like: `"&amp;#0972;"` I also had to change the replace string to: `"&$1;"`

Comment: I ended up with the following search pattern: `"&amp;([A-Za-z]+|#?[0-9]+);"` and the following replace string: `"&$1;"`

Comment: I should mention that this replace scheme actually removes leading 0s from the numeric entity, however this doesn't seem to affect rendering of the entities. Also, using `"\d+"` instead of `"[0-9]"` didn't work for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: Okay, back references are implementation-dependent. Some use backslashes, some use the dollar sign. I've edited the regex to include proper support for decimal and hexadecimal numeric entities.

Comment: Whoops, you are right. Damn. ;-) I'll remove the second regex.

Comment: This works marvelously. `"&amp;(#?[0-9]+|x?[0-9A-Za-z]+);"` It matches `&foo;` or `&#1234;` or `&x7e;` As well as a previously un-noticed side effect of matching corner cases such as: `&frac12;`. Tomalak your approach of capturing the entity value rather than the &amp; portion is way more effective than how I initially thought I should be directing my efforts. Thank you very much. I have learned a lot about RegExes today!

Comment: Also, in reference to your suggestion about parsing with the DOM, I am. Therein lies the problem. jQuery is converting the ampersands to &amp; when converting the nodes back to text. So I need to strip them after the fact. Process is as follows: Copy all text from textarea into a temporary DOM node, walk the nodes to find text nodes and attributes (alt & title only) and replace any non-ASCII characters with their entities then convert the DOM nodes back to text and place them in another textarea. After reading Spolsky & Atwood rant about parseing HTML with RegEx I thought this was best.

Answer (score 2):

I gather that you want to match `&amp;`, but only if it is followed by an alphanumeric character or certain punctuation. That calls for *lookahead*. This regular expression should match what you want without capturing *or consuming* any additional characters.

`(&amp;)(?=[#?a-zA-Z0-9;])`

Comment: This didn't do anything in Firefox... though I haven't checked other browsers. Are lookaheads supported by JavaScript regular expression engines?

Comment: Mozilla developer reference says yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Rob Kennedy: You are wrong here `[#?a-zA-Z0-9;]` - this is a character class that matches *any single one* of these characters (no quantifier!). Also, a character class has no order, so it would be equivalent to, say `[?0-9;#a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: Tomalak, you have accurately described my regular expression. How is it wrong? If any single one of those characters follows `&amp;`, we want the regex to match. We don't care what *else* follows, as long as the first character is in that character class. At least, that's what the original regex specified. The ordering I chose was simply parroting the order shown in the question. It's neither important nor relevant.

Comment: Tomalak correctly gathered that I was intending to match HTML character entities, which require quantification, or, at least matching the semicolon after a qualifying single character.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're *matching* the string `&amp;l` but *captured* is only the `&amp;`. This is because of the character class after the capture group which will match an additional character.

But your original regex is a little flawed to begin with anyway. A (not optimal) replacement might be:

```
&amp;(#[0-9]+|#x[0-9a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+);
```

which will match the complete entity or character declaration and capture the `&amp;`.

Comment: This will match `"An ampersand &amp; and a semi-colon ;"`

Comment: Now it's better. The parentheses around `&amp;` are not necessary, but the non-capturing group around the rest of the match is counter-productive. How would you replace the match? :)

Comment: Oh well, I still was in the OP's original world, where he wanted to capture the `&amp;`. Sure, for all practical purposes it's useless but anyway :-). I used a non-capturing group to not confuse anyone with two captures where one would be expected originally :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match `&amp;`, why did you include the character class `[#?a-zA-Z0-9;]` as well?

In english, your expression would be "Match `&amp;` followed by a character that is #, ?, a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter or ;".

Just use `(&amp;)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant:

```
"&amp;([#a-zA-Z0-9]+;)"
```